# What is the verb for describing the movement of a cat's paw when it is trying to hit something with it?

Tags: word-choice

What is the verb for describing the movement of a cat's paw  when it is trying to hit something with it? Can I use the verb *punch*? For examle:

> The cat is **punching** the decorations hanging from the Christmas tree.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Punching* involves bending the arm and striking out forcefully with the closed fist. A cat can't make either of those movements in the way a man would. A cat playing with a dangling object usually **bats** it sideways with its paw.

You could simply use ***pawing***.

Comment: Or *batting*... :)

Comment: I am baffled how this answer, which is the accepted one, has such little votes - where as the other answer that suggests the same word now has +45. This answer was written at least 6 hours before the highly upvoted one. Strange.

Comment: @AIQ In defense of the other, it is better written.    This one can be simplified to "a cat usually bats with its paw, so using pawing".  The higher voted answer specifically calls for using "batting".  Was "bats" or "pawing" initially bolded, or was that in a later edit?   The more I compare the two, the other just seems like a more correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson The "bold" characters were edited in by Mari-Lou. But I don't see how not having italicized or bolded text makes an answer any less correct. If you boil them both down to the last element - they both suggest the same word - bat. One could argue that the highly upvoted answer saw this answer and made their own one better (not saying they did - just that I have seen this many times). There is a huge time difference.

Comment: The highly upvoted answer isn't "unique" - that is what I am trying to say - it doesn't suggest anything significantly more helpful (Is a Wiki link all that great to merit a 49 vs 8 vote split?) I am I can see a 12 - 8 split, but 49 to 8 is a bit puzzling to me.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson This incredibly great [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/228769/77766) has +22. The knowledge and effort that went into that is top class. That is an enlightening answer. I can't wrap my head around how an answer that simply suggests the same word suggested by someone else before gets a +49. May be I am being salty.

Comment: @AIQ because they don't suggest the same word... This answer suggests pawing but the more upvoted answer suggests batting. More people agree "batting" is the most appropriate term. Kate's answer uses the verb "bat" in passing but doesn't propose it as the answer to the question, and most visitors are unlikely to even read her answer closely enough to notice "bats" within it — they just look for each answer's isolated single-word responses and upvote the one where they think "yeah that's what I'd've said"

Answer (score 80):

In my experience the verb 'bat' is often used for this: *The cat is batting the decorations hanging from the Christmas tree.*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bat#Verb: 
*(intransitive) To strike or swipe as though with a bat.
The cat batted at the toy.*

As noted by others, *pawing* is also a descriptive choice. I would recommend either verb over punching (typically a more forceful action which I associate more with humans than cats).

Comment: Absolutely. Cats do not punch things because they don't have fists.

Comment: “Swiping” would also work.

Comment: Of the options, I think "bat" is the closest to "punch."  "paw" and "swipe" have different feels to them.  As a native English speaker (Southwest USA), pawing is a gentle motion, and swipe is something which is more about trying to get the claws in something (to take it, or to hurt it).  Bat is the verb I would use for trying to strike an object to cause it to move.

Comment: How about swat?

Comment: @DanielB "swiping at". I swipe things on my phone, but my cats aren't clever enough to do that yet!

Comment: Yes, of course, swiping *at*. Thank you.

Comment: Pawing is motion parallel to the paw. Batting is motion perpendicular to the paw.

Comment: Joined the sub to agree to this answer, I've always used "batting".

Comment: more with humans... or more with kangaroos

Comment: @CJDennis - Or maybe they're too clever to do that... ;-)

Answer (score 39):

The first word that came to my mind was *swatting*.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swat#Verb, with the given example

> The cat **swatted** at the feather.

Answer (score 13):

One common term for this is **batting** or **batting at**. When used with a cat (or other animal) this means hitting or tapping at something with the paw.

> The cat is batting at the decorations hanging from the Christmas tree.

Describing a cat as "batting" or "batting at" another cat or an object means the cat is striking or tapping with its paw, but not so forcefully as to be a violent attack. It usually suggests curiosity or playfulness rather than hostility.

Answer (score 9):

A very idiomatic way to say this is:

> The cat **swiped** the object with its paw.

As also used in the example by:
[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swipe)

> 1 : a strong sweeping blow
>   // a swipe of a paw

*Although less reliable, a simple search also yields many results showing it in real-life usage:
[Thanks Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cat+swipe)*

Comment: Its paw, not it's paw.

Comment: @ChrisMelville Please feel free to always edit typographical mistakes as you see them - if an edit doesn't change the meaning of the answer, it should always be accepted.

Comment: Thanks. Although from past experience on StackOverflow, edits aren't allowed which are only a few characters :)

Answer (score 4):

### Taps

It might be an internet colloquialism, but I generally see this referred to as taps. Many "cute cat videos" describe it as such, and there's even a subreddit devoted specifically to [r/CatTaps](https://www.reddit.com/r/CatTaps/).

It's worth noting that there is a fair amount of connotation depending on what kind of activity the cat (or other animal) is actually doing.

**Tapping** Moving the paw towards and away, possibly touching, usually tentative or investigative. If the tap causes the target to move, might lead to Batting.

**Batting** Connecting with a loosely hanging item with each (or most) attempts. Each successful bat sends the item swinging.

**Swiping** More aggressive, and generally directed at another animal. Hissing or growling might be involved. Claws might be out. This might be a followup to successfully batting an item.

**Pawing** Generally an attempt to retrieve or receive something such as a partially obscured/covered item, or in/near a food bowl when they're trying to explain to their human that it's dinner time.

Comment: Good one, and it looks like a few people have already used it in answers and comments here without realizing it is a possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *to punch* is the right verb here. Take a look at its definition from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/punch) dictionary:

> to punch (verb): to hit forcefully with your fist.
> *She punched him in the face after he called her names.*

As cats can't make a fist, I'd advise you not to use it. Instead, I believe *to beat* would be a good choice.

> [to beat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beat?q=to+beat) (verb): to hit repeatedly.
> The cat is beating the decorations hanging from the Christmas tree.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: I agree that since a cat can't make a fist, it can't "punch". They might ***swipe*** or ***bat***, but not normally ***punch***.

Comment: @Matthew: All I can say is I probably wouldn't say anything if a native speaker talked about a cat punching something (I'd assume they must have their reasons for the "odd" choice of verb). But it's not the kind of usage *learners* should assume is "natural". Even though *you* find it an acceptable way of describing something, I don't. And it doesn't really matter whether the *majority* of native speakers side with me or with you on this one - I certainly won't be alone in "raising my eyebrow" over what I see as an "inaccurate" description.

Comment: I agree with her statement: it's not that it is *wrong*, per se; it's just not (our) first and natural-sounding choice. I can clearly see a **figurative** use of *punch* for a cat, though.

Comment: I found [*The cat punched its head against the pillow*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+cat+punched%22) (from Google Books, in a *poem*), along with a highly anthopomorphised *The cat punched the air in delight*. But at the very least, it's an "unusual" usage compared to [*the cat **batted / swiped*** (at something).](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cat+batted%2Cthe+cat+swiped%2Cthe+cat+punched&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cat%20batted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cat%20swiped%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: **Swipe** +1. That's assuming they're *not* declawed (because then all they can do is *paw at* stuff) it's both definitions of *swipe*: "hit or try to hit with a swinging blow." and if it's an object or an animal small enough to eat: "steal."

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I've gone ahead and removed my answer and all comments, I'll keep out of this going forward, cheers

Comment: @Matthew: The way rep and voting work on SO sites is sometimes a bit "counter-productive" for topics like "use of language". After all, you're (obviously?) a native Anglophone yourself, which virtually *by definition* means you know which words you can and can't use in various contexts. I can say ***I*** wouldn't use "punch" for the cited context, and I can give my *reason* (to do with "making a fist"), but it doesn't make much for me to tell you you're "wrong" if you see things different...

Comment: ...what I'm getting at is just because your view is shaping up to be a *minority* position doesn't mean it's inherently "incorrect". But because you'd probably end up taking an unwelcome hit to your rep if you left your answer to attract more downvotes, you're naturally inclined to delete it. But at the very least I'd say it should be instructive to some learners to know that there's not 100% agreement between native speakers regarding certain usages. Whether I agree with you or not, your input here would be potentially useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

> to [slap](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slap): to hit someone or something with the flat part of the hand or other flat object

https://www.reddit.com/r/CatSlap/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the upvoted answer that *batting* is the best word.

There is another word that works, though it may be a little too cute.

The word is **boop** or **booping**.

Here's an example from [Reddit: "Kitten boops himself"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eyebleach/comments/2zr0pw/kitten_boops_himself/):

[image: Kitten hits his face with his paw]

You can find many more examples online just searching for "cat boop."

If cute is what you're going for, it's a fine choice.

It's not in most dictionaries as it's more of an onomatopoeia. I think the meaning is basically thinking of the noise that a button on, say, a cute robot would make. Often it refers to the cat's nose (since that is button-like), but it is not restricted to noses.

Comment: FWIW Booping generally refers to tapping the nose of an animal. Boop the Snoot in common parlance.

Answer (score 0):

Swiping (to swipe), cats swipe at things.

Could also be:

- Jabbing
- Pawing
- Tapping
- Poking

Answer (score 0):

nGrams reveals 'batted' to be the verb of choice (of those thus far presented) - but I think what we can conclude is that the reporting of the actions of cats has increased exponentially with the arrival of the internet...

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cat+swatted%2Ccat+swiped%2Ccat+batted%2C+cat+pawed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccat%20swatted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccat%20swiped%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccat%20batted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccat%20pawed%3B%2Cc0