# What does “their” refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, subjects

> Many Westerners are startled at the images of America and the West in
>   contemporary Japanese advertising. **Their** accidental encounter by an
>   American tourist or businessperson on a visit to Japan often evokes
>   surprise, confusion, and misunderstanding.

I'm not sure about what "Their" in this sentence refers to. I think there are three candidates for this:

1. images

   1 is like treating images like a person, so I don't feel this is the right interpretation.
2. Many Westerners
3. American tourist or businessperson

   2 and 3 are ok in the sense that they can be a proper subject of the verb "encounter", but I'm not sure why this is followed by a "by ...". Isn't this like: "His dancing by him"?

Comment: Using ***their*** to reference something associated with "something else" does ***not*** imply treating "something else" like a person in English. In your cited example, it's the *images* that can have the "quality" of "being accidentally encountered".

Comment: 'images' is the referent. THis is probably more appropriate for [ell.se]

Comment: FumbleFingers is right, and Mitch gives correctly the referent of “their”.  I want to add, however, that the extract is a classic case of how not to use pronouns.  Though “images” is the only referent that gives a sensible meaning, nothing grammatically prevents the reference from being to “Westerners”.  At best the use of “their” will make some readers/listeners uneasy and could confuse others.  One aim of good and consideration should be to avoid phrasing which force someone to go back over the sentence a second time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everyone.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica If that is right, for example, "My punch from a cat was painful" is also a correct sentence? "My punch" sounds like I punched something, but what I want to say in this sentence is that "I was punched from a cat, and that punch was painful"

Comment: @HayashiYoshiaki: I think "My punch from a cat was painful" is a "weird" utterance on many levels. For starters, I thought we established only last week that [***cats can't punch***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/236820/126)). And we don't use "his punch" to refer to *the effect [on him] of **being** punched [by someone else]*. So switching to a more normal context, it would be *The boxer's punch was painful [for/to me]*, not *My punch from the boxer...*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks for answering.